# Rails string helper to turn "SimpleProduct" into "Simple Product" or even "simple product"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Rails injects a lot of neat [helpers into String](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html) which it uses for its "magic".

I have a string "SimpleProduct" and want to represent that as "Simple Product".

Right now, I only see how to do this using four of these helpers:

```
"SimpleProduct".tableize.singularize.humanize.titleize
```

Is there a cleaner and simpler way? Am I overlooking an obvious helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running directly `"SimpleProduct".titleize` should do the work

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize

Comment: Thanks. I was quite sure I missed something obvious. And indeed, it turns out I missed the obvious :)